# IBM MQ v 9.1 installed on RHEL 8.3 not connecting in MQJExplorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ in the RHEL server in the path /home0/mqm. Further, I have made a Queue Manager `QM816` and its 2 queues - `REQUEST_Q` and `RESPONSE_Q` . The listener is also defined, which is listening on port 8030 on this server.

In my local windows machine I have MQJExplorer tool to manage the queues and look for any request in the request queue /send a response in the response queue.

The problem is queue manager is not able to connect to this queue. Showing error as:

[image: MQJError]

Error in console is shown as :

```
Path: [IBM MQSeries, Queue Managers, QM816 on 172.xx.xx.xxx(8130)]
Security exit invoked: reason: MQXR_INIT
Security exit invoked: reason: MQXR_INIT_SEC
Security exit invoked: reason: MQXR_TERM
Failed to connect to queue manager: com.ibm.mq.MQException: Completion Code 2, Reason 2035
connectSelected: com.ibm.mq.MQException: Completion Code 2, Reason 2035
```

Going through IBM documentation, it seems like a security error. Not quite able to get as new to this thing and documentation seems to be filled with jargons. Any help is appreciated...!!!

Comment: That error is not displayed by the queue manager, that is the app you are running that is displaying the error.   Review the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` file for more details on the cause of the 2035.

Comment: Thanks Josh.. the error is resolved.... it was related to channel authentication... had to remove the authentication for channels ...

Comment: @ShubhamUniyal - you could also have fixed the problem by enabling the authentication needed for your connection rather than removing channel authentication altogether. This would be a more appropriate fix.